# Cursor pointer when mouse-over on date and time picker icon on chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have a simple problem with cursor: pointer css in chrome browser but I could not solve this problem for 2 days. I will attach my code below. Please run it on Chrome browser. You will not be able to see icons on Firefox browser. Only chrome works...

```html
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        input{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
  <input type="date" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory />
  <br/>
  <input type="time" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory />
</body>
```

the result will look like above.
[image]

If I mouse over icons(red parts), then they appear only arrows.. I want to change it to pointer. Please help me if you have experience.

Thank you

Comment: where is the problem? it's a browser feature. what does this have to do with cursor-pointers?

Comment: If you mouse over date or time picker icon, the mouse cursor is arrow...   
I want to change it into pointer (hand)...

Comment: I added a new css for input{cursor: pointer}, but mouse cursor is pointer on input element.. and is arrow on picker icon...

Answer (score 13):

```html
<style type="text/css">
  input {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>

<input type="date" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory />

<br/>

<input type="time" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory />
```

Comment: Any approach to do the same in react?

Answer (score 4):

With the following approach, you can achieve what you desire:

```html
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    input#filepicker::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

   
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="date" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory style="cursor: pointer" />
  <br />
  <input type="time" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory />
</body>
```